# Modifying Legend Labels and Color Palette for Improved Visibility in ggplot2 Plot geom_path?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have used the following code to create the attached graph:

```
# Load required library
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmulti)

# Simulate data
set.seed(123)  # Set a seed for reproducibility
n_points <- 100  # Number of data points

# Simulate values for Loading variables l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, and l6
l1 <- rnorm(n_points)
l2 <- rnorm(n_points)
l3 <- rnorm(n_points)
l4 <- rnorm(n_points)
l5 <- rnorm(n_points)
l6 <- rnorm(n_points)

# Create a labelling variable with categories
labelling <- factor(sample(1:3, n_points, replace = TRUE))

# Create a data frame with the simulated data
dataplot <- data.frame(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, labelling)

# Create the plot using ggplot
p <- ggplot(dataplot,
            aes(
              Loading1 = l1,
              Loading2 = l2,
              Loading3 = l3,
              Loading4 = l4,
              Loading5 = l5,
              Loading6 = l6,
              color = labelling
            )) +
  geom_path(alpha = 0.2) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 7) +
  coord_serialaxes()

# Display the plot
print(p)
```

My questions: How can I change the labels used in the legend to make them more visible e.g. using a filled square to indicate the color? And how to change the colors used with the goal to use more distinctive colors?

[image]

Comment: Normally setting the `key_glyph` should work like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48902174/how-to-change-symbol-in-legend-without-changing-it-in-the-plot But I wonder if the `ggmulti` package doesn't respect that properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Using this question as reference
[Change ggplot coloured lines in legend to squares or circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314693/change-ggplot-coloured-lines-in-legend-to-squares-or-circles)

Original data.frame is transformed to manage color without coord_serialaxes().
It is important to add g column and use group within aesthetics declaration to plot lines along the x axis.

The strategy is to plot point with legend, then plot white points over the old points to hide them. Finally, plot lines without legend.

Also, bright colors are selected in scale_color_manual()

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- dataplot %>% mutate(g=seq(1:100)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(labelling,g),names_to = "loading",values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(loading=gsub("l","Loading",loading))

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=loading,y=value,color=labelling,group=g)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","green","blue")) +
  geom_point(shape=15) +
  geom_point(size=5,colour="white") +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_path(show.legend=FALSE) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size=0.1,color="black")) +
  xlab("") + ylab("") + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))
```

Problem with this solution is that panel.grid.major are cut.

[image]

**Solution 2**

@MrFlick's suggestion was considered [How to change symbol in legend without changing it in the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48902174/how-to-change-symbol-in-legend-without-changing-it-in-the-plot) and guides() fix the problem with cut lines

```
df <- dataplot %>% mutate(g=seq(1:100)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(labelling,g),names_to = "loading",values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(loading=gsub("l","Loading",loading))
glimpse(df)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=loading,y=value,color=labelling,group=g)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","green","blue")) +
  geom_point(shape=15,alpha=0) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_path(show.legend=FALSE) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1))) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size=0.1,color="black")) +
  xlab("") + ylab("") + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]